# Sanitizing ng-content for code snippets

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an Angular component that uses [PrismJS](http://prismjs.com/) for syntax highlighting code blocks. The component is as follows:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, Input, 
    ElementRef, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

declare var Prism: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'prism',
  template: `
  <div hidden="true" #rawContent>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
  <section class="code-container">
    <pre><code [innerHtml]="content" class="block language-{{language}}"></code></pre>
  </section>
  `
})
export class PrismComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() language: string;
  @ViewChild('rawContent') rawContent: ElementRef;
  content: string;

  constructor(public cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.content = Prism.highlight(this.rawContent.nativeElement.textContent.trim(),
        Prism.languages[this.language]);
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

The issue is that when I use it, I have to manually escape any invalid HTML characters.

I've tried using [`DomSanitizer`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer).sanitize() on both the component element reference value and the `rawContent` reference value in the following locations in order to try to circumvent this:

- constructor
- `ngOnChanges()`
- `ngOnInit()`
- `ngAfterViewInit()`

Angular throws invalid character errors before any of these events take place when the code block contains invalid HTML characters.

How would I go about sanitizing the code block specified in `rawContent` in order to prevent manually escaping invalid HTML characters?

Example [StackBlitz Solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-content-sanitize?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Why don't you have the text in a variable in the component? In your real app, will the text be hardcoded in the template?

Comment: I already have a component that does this by retrieving remotely-hosted text (GitHub, gists, etc.) by URL. See [HostedCodeComponent](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-content-sanitize?file=app%2Fprism%2Fhosted-code.component.ts) and [CodeService](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-content-sanitize?file=app%2Fservices%2Fcode.service.ts). The issue posed above is out of curiosity to see if it can actually be done. I would still use it in one-off cases where I want a quick code block rendered in a component.

Comment: Ok I get it. There is an open issue for that; without much activity though... https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11859.  I can't think of any better work around that the one suggested by @Juan Mellado for when using hard coded strings in templates

Comment: @David, given that issue, I guess defining the snippets as variables in the component is the best option. See [AppComponent](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-content-sanitize?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts), [AppComponent Template](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-content-sanitize?file=app%2Fapp.component.html), and [SanitizePrismComponent](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-content-sanitize?file=app%2Fprism%2Fsanitize-prism.component.ts). If you make an answer with this implementation, I'll give you credit for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of angular 5.2, this is currently not possible because of the way single brackets are interpreted. Using `ngNonBindable` does not work with single brackets

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11859

This will fail

```
<div>
  Test content with a bracket {
</div>
```

To include strings with backets in your template, you need to assign the string to a component's variable

```
//component.ts
 snippet = `export class Demo {
   id: number;
   name: string;
}`;

//component.html
<sanitized-prism [snippet]="snippet" language="typescript"></sanitized-prism>
```

#### SanitizePrismComponent

```
import {
  Component,
  AfterViewInit,
  Input,
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  SecurityContext
} from '@angular/core';

import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

declare var Prism: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'sanitize-prism',
  template: `
  <section class="code-container">
    <pre><code [innerHtml]="content" class="block language-{{language}}"></code></pre>
  </section>
  `
})
export class SanitizePrismComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() snippet: string;
  @Input() language: string;
  content: SafeHtml;

  constructor(public cdr: ChangeDetectorRef, public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.content = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(
      this.sanitizer.sanitize(
        SecurityContext.HTML, 
        Prism.highlight(this.snippet, Prism.languages[this.language])));
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

If you really want to hard code strings with brackets in your template file, then you can use of these solutions:

**Encode brackets**

```
export class Demo &#123; id: number; name: string; &#125;
```

(which is what you already had)

**Wrap everything in an interpolated expression**

```
{{"export class Demo { id: number; name: string; } }"}
```

Note: if the string contains douoble quotes, you need to escape them with `\"`

```
{{"  let: str = \"string\"; "}}
```

**Escape brackets** (as suggested by angular's error message)

```
export class Demo {{'{' }} id: number; name: string; {{   '}'}
```

**Wrap your code in CDATA** (@Juan Mellado's suggestion)

```
<prism language="typescript">
  <![CDATA[ export class Demo { id: number; name: string; } ]]>
</prism>
```

The last one if the cleanest way IMHO

Answer (score 2):

Use CDATA ([Character Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA)):

```
<prism language="typescript">
  <![CDATA[ export class Demo { id: number; name: string; } ]]>
</prism>
```

Comment: I would prefer a more Angular driven solution that doesn't require me to wrap my code blocks in something like this. Preferrably a means of sanitizing the data before it is rendered.